# Update JSON-like object that contains new lines and comments

Tags: node.js, json, parsing, comments

I'm working on a Node application where I make a call to external API. I receive a response which looks exactly like this:

```
{
   "data": "{\r\n    // comment\r\n    someProperty: '*',\r\n\r\n    // another comment\r\n    method: function(e) {\r\n        if (e.name === 'something') {\r\n            onSomething();\r\n        }\r\n    }\r\n}"
}
```

So as you can see it contains some comments, new line characters etc.

I would like parse it somehow to a proper JSON and then update the *method* property with completely different function. What would be the best (working) way to achieve it? I've tried to use comment-json npm package, however it fails when I execute `parse(response.data)`.

Comment: I believe what you are getting is a string in the repose from the external API. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, it looks like a string and I would like to parse it to a JSON to modify it in a convenient way. However it fails during any parse try as it contains comments and new lines characters.

Comment: Please share the exact response from the external API. The reason I am asking you for this is because a comment is not valid inside a JSON object.

Comment: What I've shared is exact response I'm receiving.

Comment: To be clear, let me know if you can define a function that produces the same response as your external API does. The rough function definition is given below:
function get_response() {
        return ""
    }

Comment: `function get_response() {
    return JSON.stringify({
        "data": "{\r\n    // comment\r\n    someProperty: '*',\r\n\r\n    // another comment\r\n    method: function(e) {\r\n        if (e.name === 'something') {\r\n            onSomething();\r\n        }\r\n    }\r\n}"
    });
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
const r = response.data.replace(/\\"|"(?:\\"|[^"])*"|(\/\/.*|\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/)/g , "");
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x)));
```

Comment: It seems that something is wrong with the regex: https://i.imgur.com/7D7bsIM.png

Comment: rawinek , Try This /\\"|"(?:\\"|[^"])*"|(\/\/.*|\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/)/g

Comment: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an HTML template for you that you can try and fiddle with in your Browser Developer Console. If you want you can also replace "console.log()" with "alert()"

```
<script>
function get_response() {     return JSON.stringify({         "data": "{\r\n    // comment\r\n    someProperty: '*',\r\n\r\n    // another comment\r\n    method: function(e) {\r\n        if (e.name === 'something') {\r\n            onSomething();\r\n        }\r\n    }\r\n}"     }); }

var resp = get_response()

console.log("Response before formatting: " + resp);

resp = resp.replace(/\/.*?\\r\\n/g, "");
resp = resp.replace(/\\r\\n/g, "");

console.log("Response after formatting: " + resp);
</script>
```